# Update SEF URL to change what is output

Tags: url, sef

Good day,

I have inherited a very old Joomla site - and the are wanting URL updates for a custom module that was developed for them.

The URL's currently contain ***car-rental-branch*** - which they want amended to ***car-rental***.

I cannot for the life of me [a wordpress dev] find where one would edit that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Joomla Stack Exchange! Which Joomla version do you exactly use?

Answer (score 2):

Joomla works with internal (for example `/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=42`) and external SEF URLs (`/some-name`). The SEF URLs are created via the menu, and the "alias" from each Menu Item and/or article is used to create the URL.

A proper way to create SEF URLs in Joomla components/modules/plugins is to use the JRoute method (or more modern: Route + namespace `Joomla\CMS\Router\Route`).

If your module has been programmed in a proper way, it will use that (J)Route method. And it will use the menu structure + "alias" of menu items or articles.

In recent versions of Joomla 3 + 4 you can search all menu items for alias "car-rental-branch" and change the alias to "car-rental". Or if it's an article that does not have a menu item, check the `Content > Articles`.

When you change the alias of a menu item, the URL will change accordingly. So you might want to add a redirection in `Components > Redirects` to redirect traffic on the old URL to the new URL.